# Need to improve the performance of a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am new to `SQL` and I'm facing some problem with the performance of a `SQL` `query`. 
I followed some points from Google and created the required `indexes`. But still not able to improve the performance.

Guide me to improve the performance of following the `query`. The `tables` have millions of records.

```
SELECT TOP 15 id, 
              field1, 
              field2 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT 0               AS ID, 
                        tblsuites.suite Field1, 
                        'Work Order'    AS Field2 
        FROM   tbljb_schedules 
               INNER JOIN tblsuites 
                       ON tbljb_schedules.tblsuites_id = tblsuites.tblsuites_id 
               INNER JOIN tblsites 
                       ON tbljb_schedules.tblsites_id = tblsites.tblsites_id 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN tblbldgs 
                            ON 
               tbljb_schedules.tblbldgs_id = tblbldgs.tblbldgs_id 
        WHERE  tbljb_schedules.tbldomains_id = 28 
               AND tbljb_schedules.internalonly = 0 
               AND tbljb_schedules.tblsites_id IN (SELECT tblsites_id 
                                                   FROM   tbllogins_sites 
                                                   WHERE  tbllogins_id = 264 
                                                          AND 
                                                  tblsites.active = 1) 
               AND ( tblsuites.suite LIKE '%1%' ) 
        UNION 
        SELECT DISTINCT 0               AS ID, 
                        tblsuites.suite Field1, 
                        'Work Order'    AS Field2 
        FROM   arcjb_schedules 
               INNER JOIN tblsuites 
                       ON arcjb_schedules.tblsuites_id = tblsuites.tblsuites_id 
               INNER JOIN tblsites 
                       ON arcjb_schedules.tblsites_id = tblsites.tblsites_id 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN tblbldgs 
                            ON arcjb_schedules.tblbldgs_id = 
                               tblbldgs. tblbldgs_id 
        WHERE  arcjb_schedules.tbldomains_id = 28 
               AND arcjb_schedules.internalonly = 0 
               AND arcjb_schedules.tblsites_id IN (SELECT tblsites_id 
                                                   FROM   tbllogins_sites 
                                                   WHERE  tbllogins_id = 264 
                                                          AND 
                                                  tblsites.active = 1) 
               AND ( tblsuites.suite LIKE '%1%' )) T 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN Charindex('1', field1) = 1 THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
          END, 
          field1
```

Comment: Could you post the schema, and the result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The schema is too big. I'm trying to do the search based on multiple conditions and keyword.@RubbleFord

Comment: I feel that you don't need  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblbldgs  in the both the queries.

Comment: You only have 6 tables, how can that be too big?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should Try the below code changes

```
SELECT TOP 15 
id,
field1,
field2
FROM
(
    SELECT 
       0 AS ID,
       tblsuites.suite Field1,
       'Work Order' AS Field2,
       SeqOne = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('1', tblsuites.suite)= 1
                THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END
       FROM tbljb_schedules
          INNER JOIN tblsuites 
             ON tbljb_schedules.tblsuites_id = tblsuites.tblsuites_id
          INNER JOIN tblsites 
             ON tbljb_schedules.tblsites_id = tblsites.tblsites_id
          LEFT OUTER JOIN tblbldgs 
             ON tbljb_schedules.tblbldgs_id = tblbldgs.tblbldgs_id
          WHERE tbljb_schedules.tbldomains_id = 28
             AND tbljb_schedules.internalonly = 0
             AND EXISTS  -- Replace IN With EXISTS
             (
             SELECT 
                1
                FROM tbllogins_sites
                WHERE tbllogins_id = 264
                AND tblsites.active = 1
                AND tblsites_id = tbljb_schedules.tblsites_id
             )
             AND (tblsuites.suite LIKE '%1%')

    UNION -- UNION Will By Default Take DISTINCT Records

    SELECT 
       0 AS ID,
       tblsuites.suite Field1,
       'Work Order' AS Field2,
       SeqOne = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('1', tblsuites.suite)= 1
                THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END
       FROM arcjb_schedules
       INNER JOIN tblsuites ON arcjb_schedules.tblsuites_id = tblsuites.tblsuites_id
       INNER JOIN tblsites ON arcjb_schedules.tblsites_id = tblsites.tblsites_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tblbldgs ON arcjb_schedules.tblbldgs_id = tblbldgs.tblbldgs_id
       WHERE arcjb_schedules.tbldomains_id = 28
       AND arcjb_schedules.internalonly = 0
       AND EXISTS 
          (
             SELECT 
             1
                FROM tbllogins_sites
                    WHERE tbllogins_id = 264
                       AND tblsites.active = 1
                       AND tblsites_id = arcjb_schedules.tblsites_id
          )
       AND (tblsuites.suite LIKE '%1%')
)T
ORDER BY
    SeqOne,
    field1;
```

Comment: Invalid column name 'SeqOneD'

Comment: A Small Typo. Updated in the answer. Please check now

Answer (score 0):

Performance tuning is a more of a trial and error subject.

Looking at your code I can see a major performance offender. This condition in the where clause:
    and tblsuites.suite LIKE '%1%'

I don't know how big is the tblSuites table but the use of LIKE '%1%' makes the optimizer perform table scans rather than index seek, so even if you have indexed that column it will be useless.

also follow what @Jayasurya Satheesh mentioned in his answer.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Unfotunatelly I can't comment on other ppl answers yet ! :)